# Netty disconnects channel after roughly 10 minutes

Tags: java, netty, channel

I've setup my netty server and everything is fine and dandy, however it disconnects channels after around 10 minutes of them being connected. I've tried adding these keys to the server bootstrap:

```
bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);
bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
bootstrap.setOption("child.TcpAckFrequency", true);
bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
bootstrap.setOption("keepAlive", true);
```

However, I didn't set these options to the client bootstrap. I'm not sure if that's a problem or not, would like some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've made a feature that sends a packet to the client every minute, and so far, so good. I think it's because I would leave the client without sending or reading any packets for a good length of time, and I guess the server disconnected it because of that.

Comment: You could also have a look at IdleStateHandler which could help you to manage this kind of issue.